# How can I display tooltips from multiple maps when mousover on one of the maps in D3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a dashboard with two separate maps of a state showing different data based on years 2014 and 2012. The map when hovered over show the name of area individually. What I need to do is display both 2012 and 2014 maps's tooltips at the same time over the respective maps when I mouseover any one of the two maps. How can I display both at the same time. I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test dashboard</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
 <style>
  #gujarat-viz-2017, #buttons {
   border-right: 1px solid #ccc
  }
  .container {
   background-color: #d5e8ec;
  }
  .const0 {
   display: none;
  }
  .emptyparty {
   fill:#f9f9f1;
  }

  .emptyparty:hover, .constituency:hover {
   fill:#ccc;
  }

  .hidden { display: none; }
  .showtooltip { position: absolute; z-index: 10000; background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px; color: #fff; padding: 5px; }

  /*Party colors*/
  .bjp{ fill: #f88101;}
  .inc{ fill: #6da736;}
  .ncp{ fill: #076598;}
  .gpp{ fill: #5a469d;}
  .ind{ fill: #25a29a;}
  .jdu{ fill: #eb4d4c;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div id="gujarat-viz-2014" class="col-md-6">
    <h2>2014</h2>

   </div>
   <div id="gujarat-viz-2012" class="col-md-6">
    <h2>2012</h2>
    
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .row -->
 </div>
 <script src="http://www.thehindu.com/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.js"></script>
 <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function map_function(map_settings){
  // Global variables
   var margin = { top: 50, left:50, right:50, bottom:50 },
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;

  // Create SVG canvas with responsive resizing
  var svg = d3.select(map_settings["htmlelement"])
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "data"+map_settings["year"])

  // Add a tooltip to visualization
  var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .attr('class', 'hidden showtooltip')
            .attr('id', "tooltip"+map_settings["year"])

  // queue and read the topojson, json data file 
  d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/17m3if") 
    .defer(d3.json, map_settings.data) 
    .await(render_map)

  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .scale(3000)
      .center([71.5, 22.3])
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

  var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)

  function render_map(error, mapshape, mapdata){

      var constituency = topojson.feature(mapshape, mapshape.objects.collection).features;


      dataMap = {};
      mapdata.forEach(function(d){
        dataMap[d.constNo] = d;
      })

      var fill_function = function(d) {
        // d3.select(this).attr('fill', "white")                       
      } // end of mousemove_function

      var mousemove_function = function(d) {
        var constinfo = dataMap[d.properties.AC_NO];
        // console.log(constinfo.constituencyName)
        // console.log(d3.select(this).data()[0].properties)
        var html = "<p>"+constinfo.constituencyName+"</p>"
        tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
                          .html(html)
                          .style("left", (d3.event.clientX - 10) + "px")
                          .style("top", (d3.event.clientY - 45) + "px");       
      } // end of mousemove_function

      var class_function = function(d) {
        var constinfo = dataMap[d.properties.AC_NO];
        var className = "constituency ";
        if(constinfo !== undefined) {
          className += ("c"+constinfo.constNo+" ")
          className += constinfo.leadingParty.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toLowerCase()
        } else {
          className += "emptyparty"
          className += " const"
          className += d.properties.AC_NO
        }                 
        return className;
      } // end of class_function

      var mouseout_function = function(d) {
        tooltip.classed('hidden', true)                         
      } // end of mousemove_function

      svg.selectAll(".constituency")
         .data(constituency)
         .enter().append("path")
         .attr("d", geoPath)
         .attr('class', class_function)
         .attr('fill', "white")
         .attr('stroke', "#e8e8e8")
         .attr('stroke-width', "0.5")
         .on('mouseover', mousemove_function)
         .on('mouseout', mouseout_function)

  } // render_map

  
} // map_function

  var gujarat_data_2014 = {
   htmlelement: "#gujarat-viz-2014",
   data: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/yolfr",
   year: "2014"
  };
  var gujarat_data_2012 = {
   htmlelement: "#gujarat-viz-2012",
   data: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/19ztxj",
   year: "2012"
  };

  map_function(gujarat_data_2014);
  map_function(gujarat_data_2012);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd modify your `mousemove` and `mouseout` to operate on both maps at the same time:

```
    var mousemove_function = function(d) {
        var constinfo = dataMap[d.properties.AC_NO];
        var html = "<p>" + constinfo.constituencyName + "</p>"
        var tooltips = d3.selectAll('.showtooltip');
        // get paths from all maps
        d3.selectAll('.c' + constinfo.constNo)
          .each(function(d,i){
            var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            // operate on appropriate tooltip
            d3.select(tooltips.nodes()[i]).classed('hidden', false)
              .html(html)
              .style("left", (pos.x + pos.width/2) + "px")
              .style("top", (pos.y - pos.height/2) + "px");
          });
      } // end of mousemove_function

    var mouseout_function = function(d) {
        d3.selectAll('.showtooltip').classed('hidden', true);
    } // end of mousemove_function
```

Running code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCxNYL6WUZCbx7gzHPAr?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for the code. it works but the issue is the information displayed in the map that is hovered over duplicates to all the tooltips instead of the data from the corresponding data file. for example you can see it when you edit this line `var html = "<p>" + constinfo.constituencyName + "</p>" + "<p>" + constinfo.leadingParty + "</p>"` how do i handle that.

Comment: @EuniceDhivya, in that case I would use `d3.local` to stash the data, so you can access outside it's closure.  See updates [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCxNYL6WUZCbx7gzHPAr?p=preview).